# Find records with at least one association but exclude records where any associations match condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In the following setup a customer has many tags through taggings.

```
class Customer
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tagging
  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

The query I'm trying to perform in Rails with postgres is to Find all customers that have at least one tag but don't have either of the tags A or B.

Performance would need to be taken into consideration as there are tens of thousands of customers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following query.

`Customer.distinct.joins(:taggings).where.not(id: Customer.joins(:taggings).where(taggings: {tag_id: [tag_id_a,tag_id_b]}).distinct )`

Explanation.

Joins will fire inner join query and will make sure you get only those customers which have at least one tag associated with them.

`where.not` will take care of your additional condition.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was my original thought but this doesn't work as it includes customers who have tags A and C. If the customer has either tag A or B it should not be included.

Comment: @Dan I could think of above solution. Would appreciate if there would some better solution

Comment: Lol, initial answer was totally different and logically wrong. Then it was changed to my answer and accepted. Good job, boys.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk Sorry brother. Didn't saw you gave the same answer.

Comment: @Dan It would be great if you can mark his answer as correct one.

Comment: @NimishGupta Thank you, bro!

Answer (score 0):

Get ids of tag A and B

```
ids_of_tag_a_and_b = [Tag.find_by_title('A').id, Tag.find_by_title('B').id]
```

Find all customers that have at least one tag but don't have either of the tags A or B.

```
#Customer.joins(:tags).where.not("tags.id in (?)", ids_of_tag_a_and_b)
Customer.joins(:tags).where.not("tags.id = ? OR tags.id = ?", tag_id_1, tag_id_2)
```

Comment: This was my original thought but this doesn't work as it includes customers who have tags A and C. If the customer has either tag A or B it should not be included.

Comment: @Dan `Customer.joins(:tags).where.not("tags.id  = ? OR tags.id = ?", tag_id_1, tag_id_2)`

Comment: @dan can you try this?  Were this was helpful?

Comment: Hey, this doesn't work - please see my comment to Nimish's answer for a solution that does.

Answer (score 0):

Let `tag_ids` is array of A and B ids:

```
tag_ids = [a.id, b.id]
```

Then you need to find the Customers, which have either A or B tag:

```
except_relation = Customer.
  joins(:tags).
  where(tags: { id: tag_ids }).
  distinct
```

And exclude them from the ones, which have at least one tag:

```
Customer.
  joins(:tags).
  where.not(id: except_relation).
  distinct
```

`INNER JOIN`, produced by `.joins`, removes Customer without Tag and is a source of dups, so `distinct` is needed.

**UPD**: When you need performance, you probably have to change your DB schema to avoid extra joins and indexes.
You can search examples of `jsonb` tags implementation.

Comment: This was my original thought but this doesn't work as it includes customers who have tags A and C. If the customer has either tag A or B it should not be included.

Comment: You have to check answer instead of copying same comment 3 times. My solution does NOT return Customer if he has either A or B tag(i.e. A and C). Instead of another two solutions.